# Atom Text Verticle line

Tags: atom-editor

[image]

How to remove this verticle line from Atom Text Editor

Answer (score 0):

there are several possible ways as stated in [this discussion](https://discuss.atom.io/t/vertical-line-in-editor/2717/26)

Add the following in your stylesheets

```
.editor {
    .wrap-guide {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

or modify atom-text-editor rule

```
atom-text-editor {
    .wrap-guide {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: atom-text-editor::shadow .wrap-guide {
  opacity: .06; //barely visible
   back .ground-color: cyan;
} .       //it worked me thanks

Answer (score 0):

The wrap guide comes from the bundled package of the same name. You can simply disable it in *Settings > Packages*.

[image]